# No SMB access when using two routers

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-router, lan, smb

I have the following network topology:

[image: Network topology]

The desktop PC is connected via WiFi to the D-Link - Router. *The problem is to access SMB-Shares on the Synology NAS*.

I can ping the NAS and also access the webinterface (via hostname or IP) on different ports. But I cannot access any SMB-Share.

When I, however, connect the Desktop PC to the Fritzbox instead (retrieving an address from the 192.168.178.xxx subnet) I **can** access the SMB-shares on the NAS.

There are **no** firewall rules on the D-Link or on the FritzBox that explicitly block any port. On the Synology there are no log entries about the attempt.

Any clue how to even find out which device is causing the trouble there?

This all had worked before, so either I screwed up a configuration part anywhere or an update caused that issue.

Comment: Is the FritzBox doing NAT?

Comment: First, are you browsing to the NAS via windows explorer, or are you typing an UNC path? While it is often easy to remove firewall rules, most home/SOHO grade routers cannot disable NAT, and often have some hard-coded firewall logic in play. if you cannot disable NAT, you will have to create port forwarding rules to forward the NAS SMB ports. Personally I've never had any luck with SOHO routers in the middle of my network. Enterprise routers are sufficiently configurable, but most of the time the only thing you can do with a soho router is put it in bridge mode and collapse both LANs into one.

Comment: @mtak yes, it does

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It might be quite an usual solution:

Looks like the D-Link-Router blocked SMB3 - Traffic. (And SMB2, too) Switching to SMB1 on my NAS solved the problem.